# Posts limit on homepage (genesis framework)

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, homepage, genesis-theme-framework

in home.php

```
// NOT working
query_posts('show_posts=3');

// NOT working
add_action( 'pre_get_posts',  'set_posts_per_page'  );
function set_posts_per_page( $query ) {

    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 3 );

    return $query;

}

genesis();
```

I searched a lot, almost always they say the 2nd solution. But i does not work for me, maybe because its genesis. Or is this outdated?

I don't want to use the custom grid stuff i just want to limit the posts on one page (the homepage in this example)

solution thx to @Milo:

its just working in functions.php and there i need a additional if is_home

```
/** reduce number of posts on homepage **/
add_action( 'pre_get_posts',  'set_posts_per_page'  );
function set_posts_per_page( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() )
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 3 );

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the hole home.php file? 
And try to set the limit under Settings-> Reading -> Blog post and see if that works

Comment: I reduced the home.php to exactly that now. So something is wrong about that code. And the settings work just as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use `posts_per_page` to set number of posts 2) your `add_action` and its associated function needs to be in your theme's `functions.php` file, not the template.

the `pre_get_posts` action is the preferred method between the two, use that one.

Comment: Thx, I taught templates are something like additional function.php's for specific pages.

Comment: @amy `functions.php` is loaded early, where the hooks need to be added. a template is loaded *after* the query happens, so it's too late to add action hooks there. using `query_posts` generates a new query which overwrites the original, which is less efficient than just catching the first query before it happens.